# Javascript go top page button

Tags: javascript

I have the code of go to top sroll function. The button that am fixed in my home page is showing when am redirecting home page i dont want that button in top of my home page i want that button while scrolling down wot i do?

Comment: i put a go to top button in my home page with the properties position fixed and top 600px .how can i hide the button in top of that page ?and it have to visible while we scrolling .

Answer (score 0):

i think i didn't get your question right but maybe you need to try "position: fixed" for the tag?! is that what you are looking for?

edit:

set your top-button to invisible:

```
#top {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

when the user scrolls you activate it!

```
$(window).scroll(function () { 
  $('#top').css("visibility", "visible"); 
});
```

when the top-button is clicked you simply hide it again:

```
$('#top').click(function () { 
  $('#top').css("visibility", "hidden"); 
});
```

Comment: when we add the positon fixed and top 300px  the button align to that property in the home page and when we srolling down it will scroll automaticly. but i dont want that button in top of the page. the button shows only when we srolling down if we not scrolling it have to hidden. wot i do?

Comment: i put a go to top button in my home page with the properties position fixed and top 600px .how can i hide the button in top of that page ?and it have to visible while we scrolling down .

Comment: you could use jquery to get the scroll event and change the css (visibility) of the button (or div) when that event is fired

Comment: try this link. in this page you can a top button on right of the page. http://www.bluwhyte.com/demo/alfarook/facilitiesl.html

Comment: Laglaglaglaglaglaglaglaglag... Strongly recommend detaching the event after it's been fired once.

Comment: thanx a lot. i will try this tomorrow nw my office time is over.